# Need guidance on job-search process

Tags: job-search

I am a post graduate student of Computer Science, doing a specialization in Data Science, in my final year. I am doing good in Machine Learning and Statistics, however I have realized my calling is at image processing, computer graphics related subjects, where I am getting generally the highest marks in the class (above 90%). I have interest in them, and I can keep on studying, programming on them even when I don't have any exam.

In my university campus recruitment, the companies come for research oriented jobs, mainly hire for data prediction related positions, where statistics and machine learning is used. So, if I want to go for image processing, mostly I will not find a recruiter through campus placement. Then next option is to search for open requirements in job sites and apply, as I do not know anyone who can refer me anywhere.

The problem is, when I search with keyword 'image processing' in job sites, they list down 1000s of jobs. I need guidance on how to decide which jobs are real, which are fake, which companies are likely to recruit me (e.g. the companies coming for campus recruitment are most likely to hire), and guidelines on preparing for the job interview will be really helpful.

I don't have much constraints apart from getting a good work environment where I can concentrate on work, rather than getting worried about politics or my security around the place.

Or if you think, is it better to forget about my own choice and just go for the jobs that are coming for campus recruitment, rather than being jobless, that also you can suggest.

Comment: Do a search for job ads with “image” in the title or description.

Comment: Can you tell us which country you are doing job searches in ?

Comment: My suggestion is to actively apply for many jobs on your own instead of waiting for "jobs that are coming for campus recruitment".  Many websites such as LinkedIn have lots of good positions posted by various companies. In addition, it's faster for you to apply and get a job on your own rather than applying to some third-party staffing and recruiting companies (in the US).

Answer (score 1):

Don’t base your job searching solely on 1 method/avenues.

There are multiple avenues for job searching nowadays, which include Job recruitment and professional networking, like LinkedIn, Indeed, Glassdoor or local websites.
You can also company websites and look for any listed vacancies matching your preferences, skills and education.
You also have the option of getting in touch with recruitment agencies.
You can also send Emails to companies even if they do not have any vacancies posted on their websites, or networking sites (such as LinkedIn). They could either be planning to post a vacancy (you never know) or get in touch with you for a vacant position in the future.
When searching, use keywords related to your preferred area. You can also search online for terminologies and then search for job vacancies by them.